# Windows Directory Size Differences Between Applications

Tags: c#, windows

I am writing a 32-bit c# application that returns the overall size of a directory by getting file information from kernal32.dll FindFirstFile. This has triumphed over enumerating each directory in the regular fashion, and I am able to keep resource use extremely low.

A quick overview of how this works is as follows:

- Step 1 - Enumerate root directory getting all sub-directories and using FindFirstFile to collect size information for each file within this directory.
- Step 2 - Spawn child threads (up to 20) to perform step 1 against sub-directories
- Step 3 - Recurse until directories are exhausted and all file information has been collected.

This can be seen in the following Code sample where FileSystem.GetFiles is my class that utilizes kernal32 methods to get file information.

```
      private static void recurseDirectories(string directoryA, bool paramInitialPass)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] currentDirs;
            if (paramInitialPass)
            {
                currentDirs = new string[1];
                currentDirs[0] = rootDirectory;
            }
            else
                currentDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryA);

            for (int i = 0; i < currentDirs.Length; i++)
            {

                string threadInfo = currentDirs[i];
                numThreadsQueued++;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(getDirectoryFileInformation), (object)threadInfo);
                while (numThreadsQueued - directoriesProcessed > 20)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(30);
                }
                if (paramInitialPass)
                    recurseDirectories(directoryA, false);
                else
                    recurseDirectories(currentDirs[i], false);
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return;
    }


    private static void getDirectoryFileInformation(object paramDirectoryFilePathA)
    {
        try
        {
            string directoryPathA = (string)paramDirectoryFilePathA;
            List<FileData> filesDirectoryA = new List<FileData>();
            if (Directory.Exists(directoryPathA))
            {
                    filesDirectoryA = FileSystem.GetFiles(directoryPathA);
            }
            foreach(FileData file in filesDirectoryA)
            {
                Interlocked.Add(ref sizeOfFiles, file.Size);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfFiles);
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref directoriesProcessed);
        }
    }
```

These two methods are called using the following code:

```
 ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(30, 500);
 Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
 rootDirectory = share["Path"].ToString();
 recurseDirectories(share["Path"].ToString(), true);
 while (numThreadsQueued != directoriesProcessed)
 {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }
```

This code has performed flawlessly while enumerating most directories. I am able to recurse a 3TB fileshare getting total file sizes and number of files in about 8 minutes while keeping the cpu below 3% and using 15MB of memory.

Now comes the issue...

When getting the sizes for small directories (1-200 GB) I do not see any major discrepancies from what Windows says when looking at directory properties. I have however, noticed some major differences when getting the size of large directories (2-3TB).

For example:

Say I am looking at directory D:\TestDir which is DFSR Replicated to another server.
Windows says this directory is 2,949,944,019,217 bytes, or 2,974,186,774,528 bytes on disk (2.68 TB or 2.70 TB respectively).
My program says this directory is 3,009,619,048,759 bytes or 2.737 TB.
FSRM says a quota setup on the same directory has 2.71 TB usage.

I know the difference is partially due to Windows not including hidden files in their size, but when I add the total size of hidden files in the directory (87GB) to the Windows value, I get ~2.78 GB which still differs from my value. Can anyone shed some light on what else my be causing these size differences? Also, does anyone know how FSRM determines quota usage?

Eventually I want to replace FSRM quotas with a monitoring system using my data, but if my data doesn't correspond with what Windows says I could get false alarms on disk usage.

Comment: Haven't looked into it at all, but could it be that for small files, one is reporting actual size of the data, and the other is reporting the size of the allocated disk space?  I believe the minimum allocated size for a file is 4K, regardless of how little data it has in it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Bobson, I do believe the the Windows "Size on Disk" takes this into account yielding the 2.70 TB value. I say this because if you look at the properties of a file that is under 4K, it will say " Size: x bytes, Size on disk: 4.00 KB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some in depth testing this ended up being a bug with the kernal32.dll FindFirstFile method:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern SafeFindHandle FindFirstFile(string lpFileName, out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData)
```

This function returns a class "WIN32_FIND_DATA" that contains information about a specific file including name, size, last modified time, etc. I ran a test where I compare the sizes returned by this function with the size returned by the System.IO.FileInfo class and found some obvious differences on a very small set of files. When running this against a fileshare containing ~1.5 million files, two files had significantly different sizes returned as follows:

FILE 1 

Size according to FileInfo: 18158717658 bytes

Size according to WIN32_FIND_DATA:    978848478 bytes

FILE 2

Size according to FileInfo: 18211490304 bytes

Size according to WIN32_FIND_DATA:  1031621124 bytes

In both cases the difference in size is almost exactly 16 GB.

To get around this issue I am going to still use Kernal32.dll functions to get the file paths, but use FileInfo to get sizes. This seems to yield good results without affecting performance.

Comment: To wrap up, it would be good to discover exactly why FileInfo (or rather the WinAPI function GetFileAttributesEx which is what FileInfo uses internally when available) gives a different result.

Comment: I agree, although I found a work-around I would not consider this issue resolved. I am going to keep looking into this and will post any information I can uncover.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your application is compiled as 32-bit.  Are you running it on a 64-bit system?  You may be encountering filesystem redirection, for example when a 32-bit application attempts to read `C:\Windows\System32` you actually get `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.  You might need to p/invoke [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743.aspx).

So, `FileInfo` may deal with correctly reporting the size of very large files, but although that may make your answers consistent they still will not be correct.  Why are you using p/invoke anyway?

In addition, NTFS filesystem supports hard-linking where a single file has multiple directory entries.  But it only uses disk space for its contents once.  You could probably handle this by reading the "link count" metadata and dividing the file size by that field.  In this case you will need to p/invoke the Win32 API.  You might also want to use `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` (after opening the file with query rights) instead of the information in the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure.

This problem is more difficult than it looks.

Comment: My application is 32-bit, and my current testing is on a 64-bit system. My code does handle filesystem redirection by checking if the process is 64-bit and using the Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection and Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection methods. The hard-linking is a good idea to look into and I will write up some code to test this theory.